# Equivalent of beamer pause for other document classes

Tags: beamer, pause

Is there some way to obtain the same functionality as the `beamer` `\pause` command, but for any kind of document class?

Comment: Where is the sense in such a command for e.g. the `article` class?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I want to make a presentation, but using a non-`beamer` document class. But I think even the `article` class may benefit from this, e.g. for animated figures.

Comment: Other valid use case: I found this while looking for a way to create different versions of a tikz image, with shared content. In the presentation I used `\pause` but for the printed document I need to draw several states from it as individual pages. Using `\pause` can avoid copying the shared elements

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to imagine, how you will use `\pause` in a non-presentation.

Maybe layers in a pdf document will give you a similar behaviour.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} % set input encoding
\usepackage{ocg-p} 

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
%Parameter: {ocg}{name}{id}{visibility}
\begin{ocg}{Level 3}{two}{0}
\item Two
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{Level 3}{three}{0}
\item Three
\end{ocg}
\end{itemize}

\showocgs{two}{show 2}
\setocgs{two three}{}{}{show 3}%show 2+3

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The 2nd and 3rd item are not visible.
When you push `show 2` the next item is shown, with `show 3` you see all items:

[image]

Attention: This feature does not work with all pdf-viewers.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do this kind of thing until I learned how to get the results I wanted with `beamer`:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\margins{5em}{5em}{5em}{5em}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\nobottombuttons
\usepackage[display]{texpower}
\begin{document}
\section*{Pausing}
\lipsum[2]\pause

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

`pdfscreen` is a useful package, meant more for preparing documents to be read on screen than presentations to be displayed with a beamer; I was abusing it somewhat, but perhaps output like this is what you have in mind?