# Gradually revealing article parts

Tags: presentations, online

I would like to gradually reveal theorems, equations, items, etc., similar to the way done in beamer, but in a regular latex document. So a new page should be generated for each additional theorem, etc., but when the page is complete, it looks like the original article. Preferably, it should require as few changes as possible to the article (which is already written as a regular document). The goal is to use it for online teaching, where students see it on their screens, and I'm talking in the background. Is there a package or trick that would do it?

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131290/194703)?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of it. It is the same question, but the answers there don't seem very satisfactory...

Comment: simplest would just be to use beamer, since it must be essentially a presentation not a printed document

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, actually looking there again, it seems that `texpower` provides what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that solved your problem. ;-)