# How to apply animation systematically for explaining given solution

Tags: animations

Question: In my document i want to give effect of animation in systematic order. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

what i done so far

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=1.30cm, right=1.30cm, top=1.30cm, bottom=1.30cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\large
\textbf{Example: Obtain first order derivative of the function} $\boldsymbol{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}}$ 

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \left[\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right]&=\dfrac{(x^2-1)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left\{x^2+1\right\} - (x^2+1)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left\{x^2-1\right\}}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{(x^2-1)\cdot\left\{2x+0\right\}-(x^2+1)\cdot\left\{2x-0\right\}}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{(x^2-1)\cdot\left\{2x\right\}-(x^2+1)\cdot\left\{2x\right\}}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{2x\left[(x^2-1)-(x^2+1)\right]}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{2x\left[x^2-1-x^2-1\right]}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{2x\left(-2\right)}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{-4x}{(x^2-1)^2}&\\[16pt]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you meant by "animation in systematic order"?

Comment: I mean that each steps display one after another just like in presentation

Comment: In presentation, it is actually two pages for two object makes it look like animation. So you can do it by hand.

Comment: Just to remind, what animation was and still is: https://www.awn.com/animationworld/disney-artists-share-their-stories-and-creative-secrets-sketchbook … changes frame by frame..

Answer (score 0):

[This is a nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131290/108724) but it doesn't work inside multi-line math formulas. here is my trick that is a bit awkward:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=1.30cm, right=1.30cm, top=1.30cm, bottom=1.30cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\large
\textbf{Example: Obtain first order derivative of the function} $\boldsymbol{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}}$ 



\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \left[\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right]&=\dfrac{(x^2-1)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left\{x^2+1\right\} - (x^2+1)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left\{x^2-1\right\}}{(x^2-1)^2}\\[16pt]
\end{align*}\newpage

\large
\textbf{Example: Obtain first order derivative of the function} $\boldsymbol{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}}$ 

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \left[\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right]&=\dfrac{(x^2-1)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left\{x^2+1\right\} - (x^2+1)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx} \left\{x^2-1\right\}}{(x^2-1)^2}\\[16pt]
&=\dfrac{(x^2-1)\cdot\left\{2x+0\right\}-(x^2+1)\cdot\left\{2x-0\right\}}{(x^2-1)^2}\\[16pt]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It means that this type of effect is possible only in beamer class

Comment: Once again Let me tell u what I am looking for. I want to present this entire solution in step by step vertically just by using single click every time.

Comment: So what is my answer about?

Comment: the blinking is so fast

Comment: @anis GIF fixed.